# Мелькают страницы при переходе на другую страницу

Tags: html, css

Мелькают страницы в **Yii2**. Это особенность **Yii2**, или чего-то другого, какие то нюансы **php**, **html** или **web-разработки** в целом ?

Если я устанавливаю низкую скорость трафика через стандартное приложение для разработчиков, и запускаю сайт ( даже тот сайт который по умолчанию идет в **basic**), мелькает страница.

**Что происходит:**

**1.** Я нахожусь на страницы index.php

**2.** Я нажал кнопку в навигационном меню сайта, на "About", которая ведет к index.php?r=site%2Fabout.

**3.** Начался процесс загрузки страницы и её ресурсов.

**4.** Страница index.php, еще видна, но что то уже загружается... загружается...

**5.** Полностью белая страница, без ничего . Такое ощущение что я запустил пустую страницу с расширением .html Ресурсы активно загружаются.

**6.** Страница еще белая. Ресурсы активно загружаются.

**7.** Вдруг, в один момент , словно большой взрыв во вселенной, все проявилось, и страница полностью отобразилась со всеми своими элементами.

---

**Вопрос:** **Как выйти из этой отвратительной, неприятной ситуации, и почему так неправильно работает что-то..., что именно?**

---

**Должно быть так :**

**1.** Нажали кнопку перехода на другую страницу, с первой страницы.

**2.** Все начало загружаться, но первая страница еще видна.

**3.** Полностью загрузилась вторая страница, И именно в этот момент, а не в какой-нибудь другой, первая страница должна исчезнуть, а вторая появиться.

Comment: Как правило, на процесс отображения влияют блокирующие ресурсы. Например, `js` в `head` части. Вопросы производительности, довольно обширны и затрагивают множество тем. Однозначно ответить на причины такого поведения, в вашем случаи это нужно быть телепатом, потому что не ясно, что у вас там происходит, что написано в коде. Всеравно что подогнать машину в мастерскую и попросить мастера определить, не залезая под капот, почему машина медленно ездит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правильно сказал @Olegatro, посмотрите какой ресурс загружается у вас так долго (к примеру это удобно посмотреть в Developer Tools от Chrome).

Если у вас Yii2, вероятно (телепат моде он) у вас где-то затык в `yii\debug\Module`. Попробуйте отключить режим разработки, и посмотрите, есть ли разница? (телепат моде офф).

В Yii2 basic это делается так: Надо заккоментировать строчки

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
```

в index.php

Если у вас шаблон advansed, то через команду `init`